# SilverStripe Template calling function within an if statement

Tags: php, silverstripe

I would like to run a function with an if statement in the template file.

It should be easy enough but when add the function within the if statement nothing is returned.

The function and conditional statement works as I can call the function outside of the conditional statement and the other data within the conditional state are returned.

page.php

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

   public function thisIsAFunction() {
    return "I am a function";
   }    

}
```

page.ss

```
Hello, $thisIsAFunction
```

Result:

```
Hello,
```

Comment: This looks like a member function, it will need to be called on an object using the -> operator. I am not familiar with silverstripe but would assume that the pagecontroller would have an instance of itself inside the view you are attempting to render. Read the documentation. It might be $controller->thisIsAFunction(); or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$thisIsAFunction` is outputting the correct value elsewhere, it sounds like there may be a scope issue. Ensure that you're not inside a `<% with %>` or `<% loop %>` block as these change scope - if so, use `$Top.thisIsAFunction`.

Comment: Thanks irogue, it was the scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your function in the Page class rather than the Page_Controller.